# Marathon on mesos failed to update resources for container

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, marathon

I'm want to running docker container on marathon.
(Both Mesos and Marathon are run on docker.)

When i run image directly by docker run command, it's all fine and work.

But when run image by marathon, it killed after a minute (60 secs), and then marathon rebuild container and still been killed after a minute and so on.

The most weird thing is i found the following log in mesos-slave

> Failed to update resources for container
> f891ffca-39c3-4b70-adae-2520864c42b2 of executor
> 'jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86' running task
> jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 on status update for
> terminal task, destroying container: Failed to determine cgroup for
> the 'cpu' subsystem: Failed to read /proc/27321/cgroup: No such file
> or directory

I've research this problem on internet, but most are solved by increase memory, and this way is not working for me, even i gave it all my memory.

log in mesos-slave

```
I0703 06:05:25.992172    18 slave.cpp:5283] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 from executor(1)@mesos1:35786
E0703 06:05:26.070716    14 slave.cpp:5614] Failed to update resources for container f891ffca-39c3-4b70-adae-2520864c42b2 of executor 'jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86' running task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 on status update for terminal task, destroying container: Failed to determine cgroup for the 'cpu' subsystem: Failed to read /proc/27321/cgroup: No such file or directory
I0703 06:05:26.070905    19 docker.cpp:2331] Destroying container f891ffca-39c3-4b70-adae-2520864c42b2 in RUNNING state
I0703 06:05:26.070940    19 docker.cpp:2336] Sending SIGTERM to executor with pid: 792
I0703 06:05:26.070894    12 task_status_update_manager.cpp:328] Received task status update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003
I0703 06:05:26.070981    12 task_status_update_manager.cpp:842] Checkpointing UPDATE for task status update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003
I0703 06:05:26.071130    12 slave.cpp:5775] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 to master@mesos1:5060
I0703 06:05:26.071277    12 slave.cpp:5684] Sending acknowledgement for status update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 to executor(1)@mesos1:35786
I0703 06:05:26.073609    19 docker.cpp:2381] Running docker stop on container f891ffca-39c3-4b70-adae-2520864c42b2
I0703 06:05:26.076584    17 slave.cpp:5907] Got exited event for executor(1)@mesos1:35786
I0703 06:05:26.082994    12 task_status_update_manager.cpp:401] Received task status update acknowledgement (UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003
I0703 06:05:26.083410    12 task_status_update_manager.cpp:842] Checkpointing ACK for task status update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003
I0703 06:05:26.171222    14 docker.cpp:2560] Executor for container f891ffca-39c3-4b70-adae-2520864c42b2 has exited
I0703 06:05:26.172829    12 slave.cpp:6305] Executor 'jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86' of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 terminated with signal Terminated
I0703 06:05:26.172868    12 slave.cpp:6403] Cleaning up executor 'jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86' of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 at executor(1)@mesos1:35786
I0703 06:05:26.173218    18 gc.cpp:90] Scheduling '/var/tmp/mesos/slaves/82f5f7aa-772c-48b8-b9e9-5675fe0b7fa9-S0/frameworks/6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003/executors/jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86/runs/f891ffca-39c3-4b70-adae-2520864c42b2' for gc 6.99999799573037days in the future
```

log in mesos-master

```
I0703 06:05:26.071590    15 master.cpp:7962] Status update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 from agent 82f5f7aa-772c-48b8-b9e9-5675fe0b7fa9-S0 at slave(1)@mesos1:5051 (mesos1)
I0703 06:05:26.071923    15 master.cpp:8018] Forwarding status update TASK_FAILED (Status UUID: 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097) for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003
I0703 06:05:26.072099    15 master.cpp:10278] Updating the state of task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 (latest state: TASK_FAILED, status update state: TASK_FAILED)
I0703 06:05:26.080749    15 master.cpp:5623] Processing REVIVE call for framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 (marathon) at scheduler-13cb0ef0-e5fb-40ac-aa5e-d8d7284e409b@mesos1:44408
I0703 06:05:26.080828    15 hierarchical.cpp:1339] Revived offers for roles { * } of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003
I0703 06:05:26.081554    13 master.cpp:8870] Sending 1 offers to framework 2b59b774-1033-4f63-b403-fce174f8155b-0004 (Spark Cluster) at scheduler-48bf92fe-e69d-4af8-8d7e-e22cc5177d02@mesos3:46594
I0703 06:05:26.081902    13 master.cpp:8870] Sending 2 offers to framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 (marathon) at scheduler-13cb0ef0-e5fb-40ac-aa5e-d8d7284e409b@mesos1:44408
I0703 06:05:26.082159    12 http.cpp:1185] HTTP GET for /master/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._3w from 10.1.21.12:65271 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
I0703 06:05:26.082294    12 master.cpp:5877] Processing ACKNOWLEDGE call 4f55a18e-37ea-48fc-8f2d-2228f95a7097 for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 (marathon) at scheduler-13cb0ef0-e5fb-40ac-aa5e-d8d7284e409b@mesos1:44408 on agent 82f5f7aa-772c-48b8-b9e9-5675fe0b7fa9-S0
I0703 06:05:26.082341    12 master.cpp:10382] Removing task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86 with resources cpus(allocated: *):0.5; mem(allocated: *):128; disk(allocated: *):128; ports(allocated: *):[50690-50690] of framework 6f16c868-e43d-4d49-aa57-2dee2bbd782d-0003 on agent 82f5f7aa-772c-48b8-b9e9-5675fe0b7fa9-S0 at slave(1)@mesos1:5051 (mesos1)
```

log in marathon

```
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,073] INFO  Received status update for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86: TASK_FAILED (Failed to get exit status of container) (mesosphere.marathon.MarathonScheduler:Thread-97)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,075] INFO  all tasks of instance [jping.marathon-eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86] are terminal, requesting to expunge (mesosphere.marathon.core.instance.update.InstanceUpdater$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,079] INFO  Removed app [/jping] from tracker (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.tracker.InstanceTracker$InstancesBySpec:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  Increasing delay. Task launch delay for [/jping - 2018-07-03T03:49:41.174Z] is set to 2 seconds 313 milliseconds (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.RateLimiter$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  receiveInstanceUpdate: instance [jping.marathon-eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86] was deleted (Failed) (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  Received reviveOffers notification: ReviveOffers$ (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  => revive offers NOW, canceling any scheduled revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  initiating a scale check for runSpec [/jping] due to [instance [jping.marathon-eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86]] Failed (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.ScaleAppUpdateStepImpl:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  2 further revives still needed. Repeating reviveOffers according to --revive_offers_repetitions 3 (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  => Schedule next revive at 2018-07-03T06:05:31.080Z in 5000 milliseconds, adhering to --min_revive_offers_interval 5000 (ms) (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,080] INFO  Acknowledge status update for task jping.eff7501c-7e86-11e8-aea3-22ffdeeedb86: TASK_FAILED (Failed to get exit status of container) (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.TaskStatusUpdateProcessorImpl:scala-execution-context-global-150)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,081] INFO  Need to scale /jping from 0 up to 1 instances (mesosphere.marathon.SchedulerActions:scheduler-actions-thread-0)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,081] INFO  Queueing 1 new instances for /jping to the already 0 queued ones (mesosphere.marathon.SchedulerActions:scheduler-actions-thread-0)
[2018-07-03 06:05:26,081] INFO  add 1 instances to 0 instances to launch
```

[Task fail message on marathon (this picture show another task id, but the message and problem are the same)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O71YD.jpg)

Is there any similar problem I can refer?

Marathon version : 1.6.352

Mesos version : 1.5.1

---

## Resolved

I found the problem finally.

The reason marathon container task been killed is docker don't know the pid that marathon create. so Docker kill the pid which marathon created.That cause my problem.

Since I add docker run command with --pid=host on mesos-slave, this problem has been solved.

[I found the solution here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-5544)

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.